# How to move an 2D character(with animation) to mouse click position in C#?

Tags: c#, unity

i am going to develop a simple game called waste collection.In which if i click on a waste the character needs to walk to certain waste and collect it. Startingly the character is in the middle position of the screen.when we click on the left side of the character,animation left walk needs to play.On the other hand,when we click on the right side of the character the animation right walk needs to play.How the clicked position is taken in this application and how the character animates to that clicked position

public class mousepos : MonoBehaviour {

```
private Animator anim;
public float speed = 1.5f;
private Vector3 target;

void Start () {
anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
 target = transform.position;
}

void Update () {
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

                **// not working why**
        if (Input.mousePosition.x <=transform.position.x) {
            Debug.Log ("haiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
                            target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
                            target.z = transform.position.z;
                            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1); 
                            anim.SetInteger ("Direction", 1);

        }

        else if (Input.mousePosition.x >=transform.position.x) {
            Debug.Log ("pooooooooooooooooooooooiiiiii");

                            target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
                            target.z = transform.position.z;
                            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1); 
                            anim.SetInteger ("Direction", 1);
                    }




            }
 transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target,speed * Time.deltaTime);
}    
}
```

Comment: its moving fine but animation is not working

Answer (score 1):

You should convert you mouse position first using ScreenToWorldPoint before you compare it with transform position

Remember that Input.mousePosition returns your cursor position on screen(Vector2), not on world point(Vector3)

you might find your answer here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/61532/unity-2d-tutorial-getting-started on "Controlling Sprites" section